# Android: How to organaze layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to organize complicated Activity with many Views inside.

Also layout should depending on screen orientation.

[image]

Inner elements - it actually some templates.

Help me please to find out what is the best way to organize this?
Should I create layouts dynamically or I can create some xml templates and use them?
And if I want to realize Template3 as clickable element is it enough to define onListItemClick for ListView (ListItem has an xml declaration, so the ids will be the same for all elements).
And all the template elements should have the same width and height. It's OK with the ListView, But what to do with Template1? I want each items has the same height, and match parent view.

How to organize onConfigurationChanged() ? Where and how I can realize adding or removing 3 additional Template1 elements? Dynamically? Or create 2 xml?

What is the best for performance?

Maybe someone can give me a link to "example of complicated layout" or something like this? :)

Comment: Use xml for all static layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching on concept of fragmentation,it will solve the problem.

Comment: How in this case will you use the same two fragments on the one activity?